# How must I import all music files to my application?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-sdcard

So I have heard of the method `MediaStore`, but I'm finding it really hard and confusing to create some code that could help me with retrieving music files from my entire device and not just a singular folder. I've tried examining many source codes but they're all so long and confusing. I would like to know a good method that retrieves music from the entire device.

Many of the answers from related questions here don't really explain what to do. It's either. A link or "Try This" and I find it unclear and hard to understand.

My `SongsManager.Java` code -

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = ("/sdcard/Music");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /*
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     */

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())!=null && home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0){
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /*
     * The following class filters all files that have an extension of .mp3||.MP3
     */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
```

Alright, I found a way to do so using this code -

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getPath() + "/";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";

// Constructor
public SongsManager() {

}

/**
 * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
 * ArrayList
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}

private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
    if (directory != null) {
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private void addSongToList(File song) {
    if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
        HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        songMap.put("songTitle",
                song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
        songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

        // Adding each song to SongList
        songsList.add(songMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to get all media files in your device.All the Best :)

```
 String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    //your projection statement 
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
    };
    //query 
    cursor = this.managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            null);


    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            songs.add(cursor.getString(0));
            songs.add(cursor.getString(1));
            songs.add(cursor.getString(2));
            songs.add(cursor.getString(3));
            songs.add(cursor.getString(4));
            songs.add(cursor.getString(5));
            album_id.add((long) cursor.getFloat(6));
    } 
    int a[]= new int[]{R.id.textView1 ,R.id.textView3};//, R.id.textview2};
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.items, cursor, new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,           MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST/*, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION*/} ,a);
            setListAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

Comment: how do you get the path of the file?